# How do I prevent System.Security.VerificationException for unsafe code on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mailkit, mimekit

i'm developing an ASP.NET Web API 2.0 application based on .Net Framework 4.7 and i'm getting this error while i'm trying to send emails using MailKit. In local my apps runs fine, but when i publish in the hosting, based on Windows Server 2012, i got MikeKit.ParserOptions exception and i can't send emails.
Here my postman error:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The type initializer for 'MimeKit.ParserOptions' threw an exception.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.TypeInitializationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at MimeKit.MimeMessage..ctor()\r\n   at AgriturismoIlMelogranoNet.Controllers.EmailRequestController.Post(EmailRequest emailRequest) in C:\\Users\\magar\\source\\repos\\AgriturismoIlMelogranoNet\\AgriturismoIlMelogranoNet\\Controllers\\EmailRequestController.cs:line 20\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "The type initializer for 'MimeKit.Utils.CharsetUtils' threw an exception.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.TypeInitializationException",
        "StackTrace": "   at MimeKit.ParserOptions..ctor()\r\n   at MimeKit.ParserOptions..cctor()",
        "InnerException": {
            "Message": "An error has occurred.",
            "ExceptionMessage": "Operation could destabilize the runtime.",
            "ExceptionType": "System.Security.VerificationException",
            "StackTrace": "   at MimeKit.Utils.OptimizedOrdinalIgnoreCaseComparer.GetHashCode(String obj)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)\r\n   at MimeKit.Utils.CharsetUtils.AddAliases(Dictionary`2 dict, Int32 codepage, Int32 fallback, String[] names)\r\n   at MimeKit.Utils.CharsetUtils..cctor()"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to install System.Text.Encoding.CodePage, but it hasn't resolved my problem.
Than I thought that the problem has to be related with the hosting, so I edited my web.config adding:

```
  <location path="site.it" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
      <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But, it did not helped.

My controller code:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] EmailRequest emailRequest)
{
    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sistema automatico", Username));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(To));
    message.Subject = "Richiesta da parte del cliente " + emailRequest.Name;

    var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
    bodyBuilder.TextBody = emailRequest.Message;
    message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

    using (var client = new SmtpClient(/*new ProtocolLogger(Console.OpenStandardOutput())*/))
    {
        // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
        client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
        client.Connect(Host, Port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

        // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
        client.Authenticate(Username, Password);
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? My hosting provider il called Aruba.
Thank you

Comment: MimeKit uses `unsafe` code and your ASP.NET web service isn't configured to allow that. Perhaps someone can expand on this comment to give you an actual solution.

Comment: So do I need to contact the hosting service?

Comment: I don't know because I don't write ASP.NET applications.

Comment: I changed your title so that maybe someone who knows an answer will spot it

Comment: The app's Trust Level needs to be elevated to Full. I think your host will need to handle this. http://dotnet4hosting.asphostcentral.com/post/SOLVED-Operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-ASPNET-45-Hosting.aspx

Comment: @mxmissile i just emailed the host and they wrote me enabling the full trust will expose my website to security issue. Is that true? They want me to sign a disclaimer.

Comment: That is possible if you expose holes, but up to how you code your app. Its perfectly possible to build your app in a secure way with Full Trust.